# Partial Create view with ViewModel has a data type mismatch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using a ViewModel for a create action, which consists of an entity with type `Device` and two `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to poulate 2 dropdownlists while creating a new item.

```
public class DeviceEditViewModel
{
    public Device dev { get; set; }

    public int SelectedManufactor { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ManufactorListItems { get; set; }

    public int SelectedCategory { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoriesListItems { get; set; }

}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new DeviceEditViewModel
    {
        CategoriesListItems = repo.GetCategories().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ID.ToString(),
            Text = x.Name
        }),
        ManufactorListItems = repo.GetManufactors().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ID.ToString(),
            Text = x.Name
        })
    };
    return View(vm);
}
```

There is per se nothing wrong with that, as I can create, read and update everything just fine. 
Now I wanted to update my Index View to hold a partial Create View. On the right side of the page, there should be the same create form as in the standalone view.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Create", new DeviceEditViewModel()); }
</div>
```

Now upon running this, I recieve the following error (free translation):

```
"SelectedManufactor" is of type "System.Int32", but requires the type "IEnumerable<SelectListItem>".
```

The Index view renders and wants to call the Create Method in the device controller. The Create method instanciates a new `DeviceEditViewModel` and populates two `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Why does this fail in the partial View, but not in the regular View - And how can I solve this?

**UPDATE**
Lins answer was not totally correct, but brought me on the right track - which in my world counts as an upvote and an acceptance as the answer.

What I've done is created an `DeviceIndexViewModel`, which holds the EditViewModel, which is needed for creating/editing Devices.

```
public class DeviceIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Device> Devices { get; set; }
    public DeviceEditViewModel DeviceEditViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Now the Index Action needed to be updated accordingly:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        DeviceIndexViewModel vm = new DeviceIndexViewModel();
        // ...
        // omitted
        // ...
        vm.DeviceEditViewModel = new DeviceEditViewModel() 
        {
            CategoriesListItems = repo.GetCategories().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name
            }),
            ManufactorListItems = repo.GetManufactors().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name
            })
        };
        return View(vm);
    }
```

Now I could call the PartialView with:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Create", Model.DeviceEditViewModel); }
```

And finally tell the partialView to call a specific method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Device", FormMethod.Post))
{
    // ... omitted
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have another view model on the same page?? I ran in to this issue and there was nothing wrong with my @Html.DropDownList or my view model.

Comment: Yes, the Index View is strongly typed to a model `IEnumerable<Device>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the `DeviceEditViewModel` like below, then use it as strongly typed view in your `Index` View, then pass the object `DropDownListViewModel` to your partial view.

```
public class DeviceEditViewModel
{
    public Device dev { get; set; }

    public DropDownListViewModel DropDownListViewModels { get; set; } 
}


public class DropDownListViewModel
{
    public int SelectedManufactor { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ManufactorListItems { get; set; }

    public int SelectedCategory { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoriesListItems { get; set; }
}
```

Pass the object `DropDownListViewModel` to your partial view

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Create", Model.DropDownListViewModels);}
```

Change your `Create` action method like below:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var vm = new DeviceEditViewModel
            {
                DropDownListViewModels = new DropDownListViewModel()
                {
                     CategoriesListItems = repo.GetCategories().Select(x => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                            Text = x.Name
                        }),
                        ManufactorListItems = repo.GetManufactors().Select(x => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                            Text = x.Name
                        })
                }
            };
            return View(vm);
        }
```

Your partial view:

```
@model DropDownListViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.SelectedManufactor, Model.ManufactorListItems)    
@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.SelectedCategory, Model.CategoriesListItems)
```

Comment: Care to elaborate? I don't understand how I can pass the `DropdownViewModel` to the View, when I actually want to create device. The dropdown items are just there to ensure the user does not enter some made up bulls***.

Comment: If you use RenderAction you can new up the view model in the controller and pass it to the view.. return("MyView",mymodel)

Comment: makes sense Lin. I will have to implement this tommorrow however. Times up for today.

Comment: Lin I discovered why I can't wrap my head around your solution: My `Index` View uses a model of `IEnumberable<Device>` while my create model is `DeviceEditViewModel`. I just can't use the editviewmodel since it doesn't support the index view. If I change it to fit it, I can't use it anymore to create devices.
I need to keep using to differend models altogether in those two views